# XML Parsing with Jquery for IE7+ and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer, jquery-xml

I have been working on a web application where I need to parse my xml in jquery. I am building my web app to work on IE7 to IE10 and in mozilla. I wanted to iterate to my xml so I wrote below code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var xml = '<root><cell id="1"> </cell><cell id="2"> </cell></root>';       
        //works in ie7
        $(xml).filter("cell").each(function () {
            alert('ie'+$(this).attr('id'));
        });
       //works in mozilla
        $(xml).find('cell').each(function () {
            alert('mozilla'+$(this).attr('id'));
        });
    </script>
```

But what i found is that i need to write different looping mechanism to fetch from xml for different browser. Which is kind of weird as I am using Jquery so it should be all browser compatible.

So is there a better way of reading from xml which will work in all browsers so that i dont have to write browser check code?

Comment: I think because $(xml) is HTML DOM and not an actually XML Document IE wouldn't recognise tags such as root and cell and it might explains why find() would fail on IE as IE wouldn't see them as tags.

Comment: @gillesc That doesn't explain why `.filter()` **would** work in IE, though.

Comment: It seems like in IE7 it's stripping out the root node, and returning a jQuery object that contains only the child elements (the `cell` nodes). Try calling `$.parseXML(xml)` first, then passing the result of that to a jQuery object: `var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);$(xmlDoc).find('cell').each(...);`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Your logic works perfectly fine I just checked it. Thanks my brother. But shouldnt this be handled by jquery in their latest releases?

Comment: @thinkmmk If you pass a string to the `jQuery()` (or `$()`) function it attempts to parse it as HTML, because that's what it's designed to do. There's no easy way for them to check whether the string you passed was actually XML, and parse it as XML instead, which is why they provided a completely separate function (`jQuery.parseXML()`) to do it. It's up to you to know whether you're working with HTML or XML and use the functions provided accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use jQuery's main `$()` function to parse XML. It attempts to parse the XML as HTML using an HTML element's built-in `innerHTML` property, which does not work properly but comes close enough to lull people into a false sense of security. Use [`parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

$(xmlDoc).find("cell").each(function () {
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```